# iOS 6 WebDriver compilation

Tags: iphone, testing, webdriver

I tried to compile Selenium WebDriver for iPhone 6.1.3 and got some errors, like

```
Objective-C declarations may only appear in global scope
```

in HTTPVirtualDirectory+FindElement.mm file.
I use XCode 4.6.2 , iOS 6.1 SDK and WebDriver sources from https://code.google.com/p/selenium/

Someone compiled WebDriver for iOS6 successfully? Had you same problem?

Also, if you have any useful information about automated **web** testing on real devices (iPhone with iOS 6) please, share it with me =)

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the iOSDriver but it is now deprecated in favor of something else, specifically the **ios-driver** created by a third party:

http://freynaud.github.io/ios-driver/

I would set that up, come back if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver
2. take trunk from https://code.google.com/p/selenium/
3. Add project from trunk to Xcode
4. In Xcode Build and run thorugh Iphone 6.1 Emulator

P.S i think that will help you